# C# Unit Test - To mock, stub or use explicit implementation

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, simple-injector, nsubstitute

This has been discussed a number of times before, but the merits in the below examples aren't obvious, so please bear with me.

I'm trying to decide whether to use mock implementations in my unit tests and am undecided given the following two examples, the first using NSubstitute for mocking and the second using a SimpleInjector (Bootstrapper object) resolved implementation.

Essentially both are testing for the same thing, that the Disposed member is set to true when the .Dispose() method is called (see implementation of method at the bottom of this post).

To my eye, the second method makes more sense for regression testing as the mock proxy explicitly sets the Disposed member to be true in the first example, whereas it is set by the actual .Dispose() method in the injected implementation.

Why would you suggest I choose one over the other for verifying that the method behaves as expected?  I.e. that the .Dispose() method is called, and that the Disposed member is set correctly by this method.

```
    [Test]
    public void Mock_socket_base_dispose_call_is_received()
    {
        var socketBase = Substitute.For<ISocketBase>();
        socketBase.Disposed.Should().BeFalse("this is the default disposed state.");

        socketBase.Dispose();
        socketBase.Received(1).Dispose();

        socketBase.Disposed.Returns(true);
        socketBase.Disposed.Should().BeTrue("the ISafeDisposable interface requires this.");
    }

    [Test]
    public void Socket_base_is_marked_as_disposed()
    {
        var socketBase = Bootstrapper.GetInstance<ISocketBase>();
        socketBase.Disposed.Should().BeFalse("this is the default disposed state.");
        socketBase.Dispose();
        socketBase.Disposed.Should().BeTrue("the ISafeDisposable interface requires this.");
    }
```

For reference the .Dispose() method is simply this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources.
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Releases unmanaged and - optionally - managed resources.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposeAndFinalize"><c>true</c> to release both managed and unmanaged resources; <c>false</c> to release only unmanaged resources.</param>
    protected void Dispose(bool disposeAndFinalize)
    {
        if (Disposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (disposeAndFinalize)
        {
            DisposeManagedResources();
        }

        DisposeUnmanagedResources();

        Disposed = true;
    }
```

Cheers

Comment: I say keep your tests as simple as possible. Mock only if the test is complex enough to require it, IMHO. If you're using VS2012 try to take advantage of [fakes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx) too. In your case here, I don't see anything wrong with your second approach (I haven't tried your code but it looks good)

Comment: @GabeThorns: But if the test is "complex enough", there might already be a problem with the test (or the class under test) :-)

Comment: I agree with @Steven Tests should not really be "Complex" as that tends to signal a code smell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both test methods seem quite bizarre to me. With the first method, you don't seem to test anything (or I might be misunderstanding what NSubstitute does), because you just mock the `ISocketBase` interface (that has no behavior to test) and start testing that mock object instead of the real implementation.

The second method is bad as well, since you should **NOT** use any DI container inside your unit tests. This only makes things more complicated because:

1. You now use shared state that all tests use, which makes all tests depend on each other (tests should run in isolation).
2. The container bootstrap logic will get very complex, because you want to insert different mocks for different tests, and again, no objects shared between tests.
3. Your tests got an extra dependency on a framework or facade that just doesn't have exist anyway. In this sense you're simply making your tests more complicated. It might be just a little bit more complicated, but it's an extra complication nonetheless.

Instead, what you should do is **always** create the class under test (SUT) inside the unit test (or a test factory method) itself. You might still want to create the SUTs dependencies using a mocking framework but this is optional. So, IMO the test should look something like this:

```
[Test]
public void A_nondisposed_Socket_base_should_not_be_marked_dispose()
{
    // Arrange
    Socket socket = CreateValidSocket();

    // Assert
    socketBase.Disposed.Should().BeFalse(
        "A non-disposed socket should not be flagged.");
}

[Test]
public void Socket_base_is_marked_as_disposed_after_calling_dispose()
{
    // Arrange
    Socket socket = CreateValidSocket();

    // Act
    socketBase.Dispose();

    // Assert
    socketBase.Disposed.Should().BeTrue(
        "Should be flagged as Disposed.");
}

private static Socket CreateValidSocket()
{
    return new Socket(
        new FakeDependency1(), new FakeDependency2());
}
```

Note that I split up your single test into 2 tests. That `Disposed` should be false before dispose is called is not a precondition for that test to run; it's a requirement of the system to work. In other words, you need to be explicit about this and need this second test.

Also note the use of the `CreateValidSocket` factory method that is reused over multiple tests. You might have multiple overloads (or optional parameters) for this method when other tests check other parts of the class that require more specific fake or mock objects.

Comment: The NSubstitute alternative (which admittedly should be split in to two tests anyway) is simply testing that the .Dispose() method was called once, and that the Disposed member has been set to true.  I don't find this particularly useful as Disposed will of course equal true if I explicitly set it to that myself?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Why would you set `Disposed` to true yourself when that's the result you need to test? What you want to test is "Disposed is false when Dispose() is NOT called" and "Disposed is true when Dispose IS called".

Comment: Your NOT and ALWAYS assertions are simply stylistic. You also make the assertion that a DI container is something more than a way of requesting dependencies, there is no requirement to use a DI framework when you want to use a DI container.

Comment: Steven, that's my point exactly, why would that function of NSubstitute be of any use.  I want to use interfaces for testing purposes ideally, would you recommend I use a factory for creating fakes (or something like FakeItEasy)?

Comment: @JimmyHeaddon: Perhaps I misunderstand your questions, but in general, you should *not* fake the class under test (SUT); you use the real thing. You fake its dependencies. And for creating fake dependencies, you can use NSubstitute. If you fake the SUT itself, there's simply nothing to test. If you find that the SUT is still hard to test when you fake its dependencies, than there is probably something wrong with your design. For instance you're probably violating the SOLID principles or you didn't practice TDD.

Answer (score 1):

You are concerned with too much. This test is testing weather or not a given implementation is correctly disposing and as such your test should reflect that. See the pseudo code below. The trick to non brittle tests is to only test the absolute minimum required to satisfy the test.

```
 public class When_disposed_is_called()
 {
    public void The_object_should_be_disposed()
    {
       var disposableObjects = someContainer.GetAll<IDisposable>();
       disposableObjects.ForEach(obj => obj.Dispose());
       Assert.False(disposableObject.Any(obj => obj.IsDisposed == false));
    }
 }
```

As you can see I fill some dependency container with all the objects in my concern that implement `IDisposable`. I might have to mock them or do other things but that is not the concern of the test. Ultimately it is only concerned with validating that when something is disposed it should in fact be disposed.